# NodeJS + Mongo How to Find and return JSON

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb

I used this tutorial to set up my project: http://cwbuecheler.com/web/tutorials/2013/node-express-mongo/

I successfully can insert users into the db and now i am trying to find them based on their id (email)

db.get('users').find({email: req.params.id}) returns a Promise and the function gets to "Sucessfully Found User, except it actually doesnt find anything?  I'm trying to get this object and return it as a response as a json

```
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var monk = require('monk');
var db = monk('localhost:27017/nodetest1');

router.get('/findUser/:id', function(req, res) {
var db = req.db;

db.get('users').find({email: req.params.id},
    function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            // If it failed, return error
            res.send("There was an error finding user");
        }
        else {
            res.send("Successfully Found User");
        }
});
});
```

Comment: Why you are overriding `var db = monk('localhost:27017/nodetest1');` with `var db = req.db;`? Check by commenting `var db = req.db;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this!

```
db.get('users').find({email: req.params.id}, function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
        // If it failed, return error
        res.send("There was an error finding user");
    }
    else {
        res.send(result); // The result should be a JSON object that you can access with result.field (example)
    }
});
```

Does that make sense? Hopefully.